# Downloading a file from a remove server

Tags: downloads

How can I download a file or directory that is on a remove server? (note: there is no ftp setup on the server, is it possible to do this w/o having to install anything on the server?)

Comment: remove = remote?

Comment: Wow... what a vague question. We need more details. If the server is already running Samba or a SSH daemon then it may be possible if you know the login credentials. What's the server Operating System to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scp answer is a good one and should work just fine if it is a small amount of files that you need transfered but if it fails or you have to stop the transfer you can use rsync.  The command would look like this `rsync -rP -e ssh username@serveraddress:"directory/file" /destinationfolder/` the r is for recursive downloads if you need a folder, the capital P is so that you can resume what had failed or been stopped prematirely and the `e ssh` tells rsync to comunicate over ssh.  Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is running SSH, you can use `scp`.

As `scp user@host:directory/SourceFile TargetFile`

If the server is not running SSH, you can install a web server or a FTP server on the server. Examples of web servers are Apache and Lighttpd. Example `sudo apt-get lighttpd` then place the files in /var/www/ and get them with `wget http://example.com/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Something you need on the other server. Normally a ssh-server should be available. So you can use sftp to get files or directories (man sftp).

Comment: If you want a graphical SFTP client, you can use FileZilla. `sudo apt-get filezilla`.